# View hierarchy not prepared for constraint UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a bug that only occurs on iOS 8.
I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITextField`. It's connected to an `IBOutlet` in Storyboard and the delegate is connected to. My ViewController has `UITextViewDelegate` implemented in my header file.
In my implementation, I set:

```
myTextView.delegate = self;
```

Now when I click on my UITextView, this error pops up:

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint:
>
> *** Assertion failure in -[UIInputSetHostView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:],

This only happens in iOS 8 and not in iOS 9.

I have tried setting a weak reference to self on the textView delegate with no results. I have also enabled Zombie Objects but it doesn't indicate anything more.

Visually, something weirds happens:

the keyboards goes all the way to the top of the screen, it kind of sticks to the top. And then it crashes.

Comment: Seems like an autolayout issue.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that but I just can't understand why...

Comment: What did you write in TextView Delegate methods ?

Comment: That's the point: I didn't write anything in there !